# Angular - how to pass callback in menu item on parent component menu

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to have a menu in my app bar that can get its menu items from child components.  I am working with the Angular Material "mat-menu" and I'm able to display the menu item but I can't seem to fire off the associated function on the child component.

The app.component.html (parent):

```
  <div>
    <mat-toolbar style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 12px">
      <div>
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button id="btnMore" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="menuData">
          <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
            <ng-template matMenuContent let-aliasMenuItems="menuItems">
              <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of aliasMenuItems" (click)="handleMenuAction(item.action)">
                {{item.text}}
              </button>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-menu>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </div>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Here is app.component.ts (parent).  It retrieves the menu data from the appService component.  It also (should) execute the callback.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getMenuData().subscribe(menuData => this.menuData = menuData);
  }

  handleMenuAction(action: Function) {
      action();
  }
```

Here is the child component "company.component.ts" which passes its menu items to app.service so they can be retrieved by app.component.  Notice the **menuData** is an object that contains an array of objects of types **string** and callback **function**.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._appService.setMenuData({
      menuItems: [
        {text: "Add Company", action: this.addCompany}
    ]});
  }

  addCompany(): void {
    this._router.navigate(['/company', 0])
  }
```

For some reason the click event handler is not showing up in my Chrome dev tools.  I would like the menu clicks to call functions, not just perform navigation.

There may be a better way to solve this problem.   If so, please provide a link to an example.  TIA.

Edit: Stackblitz is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbzoe6

Comment: Provide a stackblitz for the same

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbzoe6   Disregard the "file not found" errors...they are false.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**
According to your `stackblitz`:

You just only need to bind the `this` of child component to new menu actions to run in child scope when you decide to call menu action

something like this:

`company-list.component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._appService.setMenuData({
      menuItems: [
        {text: "Add Company", action: this.addCompany.bind(this)}
    ]});
  }
```

**Old Answer**
You can create the `menuItems$` observable in your `appService` and subscribe on it in `app.component.ts` and from child component you just add new menuItems to this observable, The menuItems in your `app.component` will have new value

Something like this

`appService.ts`

```
class AppService {
  // ...
  menuItems$: BehaviourSubject<any[]> = new BehaviourSubject([]);
  constrcutor() {}

  // ...
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
class AppComponenet {
  // ...
  menuItems: any[] = [];
  constrcutor(private appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
    this.appService.menuItems$.subscribe(newMenu => {
      this.menuItems = newMenu;
    });
  }
}
```

`child.compnenet.ts`

```
class ChildComponenet {
  // ...
  constrcutor(private appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
    this.appService.menuItems$.new(['home', 'about']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  However, I believe the problem of the click event not firing remains.  Your solution just passes along the array instead of an object that contains the array.